# Single PHP script with multiple CRON jobs > optimize into > Single CRON?

Tags: php, cron

I have a script that I run for multiple clients.

Same script, I'm just using a different GET variable to load the client credentials.

eg.

```
example.com/script.php?client=lego
example.com/script.php?client=nike
example.com/script.php?client=stackoverflow
```

I've setup multiple crons to hit the script at midnight, with each cron having a different client GET variable.

What would be the best way to run a single CRON but process all clients? So I don't need to setup a CRON each time for each client.

Answer (score 1):

There can be various solutions but without knowing the code what comes to my mind is.

Delete all crons and setup just one.

`example.com/script.php`

Inside `script.php` wrap whatever you earlier had in a function, create an array of clients and call that function for every client by passing `username`. For example

```
<?php

// if you have lots of clients and script can exhaust time limit 
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

$clients = ['lego', 'nike', 'stackoverflow'];
foreach ($clients as $client) {
    myScript($client);
}

function myScript($client)
{
    // Whatever you had in script.php earlier replacing $_GET['client'] with $client.
}
```

Hope it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks @Muhammad thanks so much! Definitely thought of this, but is this the best way to handle multiple clients? - 100 clients for example, can this scale out, surely you dont want to run that script for that long? Just wanting to understand a scalable solution if you know what I mean?

Comment: @andrewvink I think this suits your purpose. You can create a class instead to organize this code better but eventually with single cron, core concept will remain the same. I dont really know about what your script do but even if its too much processing, it shouldnt hurt doing it like this.

Comment: thanks! ok great - can give it a go! The script is making a few API queries on behalf of each client every day. Was just wondering if a queue isn't a better approach and how best to go about it?

Comment: If you want to do that using one cron. I think queue is the only approach. Implementation may differ.